# Limit size of cascade-fetched entities Jackson/JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-jpa

Considering the stack of an App with SpringBoot, MySQL, SpringData/JPA and Jackson.

I'm trying to achieve a way to limit the size of dynamically fetched entities. In simplified schema, let's assume that we have a Post with multiple comments, but for a quick preview I just want to fetch the first 10 comments altogether with the post.

I'd call the SpringData repository to load the post with ID 10, but the jackson serializer would loop trough all comments and build a potentially huge output.

The simplest way that I found would be to tell jackson to `@JsonIgnore` the field and then on the service fetch the first 10 comments and attach them to the entity on a separate field marked as transient.

```
    @JsonView(Views.Detailed.class)
    @JsonProperty("comments")
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "comment",
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @OrderBy("created_at DESC")
    @Limit(10) // This is the kind of annotation I'm looking for
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

I know I could create a Getter which implements a logic to return a sublist, but in that situation the whole list would be fetched, right?

From Jackson side, I could try to limit the serialization depth and length using a custom mapper or annotation (which would be better and cleaner), but I didn't find any way to achieve it.

Comment: You can't do that. Your current approach of querying separately is what you need.

Comment: Try with PagingAndSortingRepositor or  If you use Hibernate you can try @Filter annotation on entity

Answer (score 0):

**Limit** 
You can use limit to fetch only 10 Records

```
@Query(value="select * from user limit 10",nativeQuery=true)
```

---

**Pageable**

```
findById(@Param("userId") String userId, Pageable pageable);

Pageable topTen = new PageRequest(0, 10);
findById(userId , topTen);
```

[Jpa Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#repositories.definition)